# How to get Navbar elements to align Horizontally

Tags: html, css

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8hz7.png) [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVf5q.png) I am trying to create a basic navbar but for some reason once I add more elements it is aligning them vertically instead of horizontal. I was trying this with bootstrap 3 and could not figure out if it is an issue with the bootstap css file or something I did with my html. Any feedback or suggestions would be much appreciated!

```html
<head> 
   <title>Bootstrap Nav Bar Example</title> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default"> 
      <div class="nav navbar-nav"> 
         <li><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Koffee</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
      </div> 
   </nav> 
   
   
</body>
```

Comment: Display: inline-block on the elements, of display:flex on their container

Comment: add this to your css: `li { float:left !important; }`

Comment: @TilakMaddy That was closer but I still get get the li items to the left of my nav header

Comment: posting pictures of code is not helpful. Post the actual code and include the css and js if any.  A snippet is your best bet to getting a quick response

Comment: @DCR sorry about that this is my first time using stack overflow.

Comment: @DCR <head>
 <title>Bootstrap Nav Bar Example</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Koffee</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </div>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @DCR This seemed to fix it for the most part but still open to suggestions if better ways are possible

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I created my Webpage. Create a single class for the whole navbar. Try to adjust the padding and margin of that class in the css file.
If the problem persists then try Reducing the size, Assign Display as "inline-block" and also try assigning float to "left"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the elements inside your `navbar` class have 2 class attributes given to them. This is incorrect. Any HTML tag should have only one attribute named `class`. All your classes for that element go in there.

Flexbox is a great way to align and space items vertically or horizontally.
You can apply these styles to your ul element:

```
ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

By default, `display: flex` will display something in a row but it doesn't hurt to add thr `flex-direction: row` property as well.
You can use the justify-content property to space elements.

More information on flexbox here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp.
Should tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

the old way was using li's and using display:inline. (you should add a ul tag to your code.  A better way way is to use flex.  You'll find it will keep you out of more trouble!

```css
li{display:inline;}

.flex{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<head> 
   <title>Bootstrap Nav Bar Example</title> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default"> 
      <div class="nav navbar-nav"> 
         <li><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Koffee</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
      </div> 
   </nav> 
   
   <div class="flex"> 
         <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Koffee</a> 
         <a href="#">About</a> 
         <a href="#">Contact</a> 
      </div> 
</body>
```